# GLSL умножение матрицы на ветор

Tags: opengl, матрицы, glsl, векторы

есть такая кастомная матрица:

```
GLdouble translation[] = {
    1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0,
    0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.5,
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0
};
```

И когда ее использую в GLSL, то вместо перемещения я получаю совершенно не понятную трансформацию:

```
 gl_Position = modelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0f);
```

Но если я изменю порядок умножения, то все заработает:

```
 gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0f) * modelMatrix;
```

Или если я транспонирую матрицу, то тоже все прекрасно работает:

```
 Type translation[] = {
    1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    2.0, 1.5, 0.0, 1.0
 };

 gl_Position = modelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0f);
```

На самом деле немного не понимаю всего этого... Получается, что GLSL умножает на вектор-строку а не на вектор-столбец, правильно? Если это так, то какой из моих предложенных двух вариантов является наиболее предпочтительным, либо может существует более лучший вариант? Хотелось бы, чтобы кто-нибудь осветил этот вопрос и сказал, почему это так происходит что с этим лучше сделать...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Получается, что GLSL умножает на вектор-строку а не на вектор-столбец, правильно?

Нет. Невозможно умножить матрицу на вектор-строку, потому что при умножении двух матриц ширина первой матрицы должна совпадать с высотой второй.

У вектора-строки высота, очевидно, `1`, а ширина матрицы - `4`.

---

Хотя вы не написали, как загружаете матрицу в шейдер, я уверен, что проблема именно в этом.

`glUniformMatrix4fv` по умолчанию работает с column-major матрицами. Это значит, что если смотреть на расположение элементов в памяти, первые четыре числа в массиве образуют первый столбец ("column") матрицы, и т. д.

Ваша же матрица - row-major. То есть у вас первые четыре числа - это первая строка ("row").

Из-за этого несовпадения матрица как бы транспонируется сама.

Это можно исправить, установив для `glUniformMatrix4fv` параметр `transpose` в `1`. Тогда матрица будет загружаться как row-major.